# Android: Rotated Map View -> Counter rotate touches -> weired issue

Tags: android, rotation, android-mapview, touches

I added rotation to my MapView and it is working well except from the touches.

I followed this code [link](http://code.google.com/p/cameralert/wiki/RotateTouches) for rotating the View and for counter Rotate the Touches.

Now my problem.

Even if there is currently no rotation the touch location is calculated wrong.
For example duraing roation = 0 the y coordinate is shifted dow.

The reason is that 
      canvas.getMatrix().invert(mMatrix);
seems to get a wrong inverted matrix even if I dont rotate the canvas.

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    //canvas.rotate(rotation, getWidth() * 0.5f, getHeight() * 0.5f);
    canvas.getMatrix().invert(mMatrix);     
    Log.d("matrix", mMatrix.toString());
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The Log says that the matrix is: (during no rotation)
     Matrix{[1.0, -0.0, 0.0][-0.0, 1.0, -38.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this is as follows:

```
    private Matrix invertedMatrix = new Matrix();
    private float[] tempLocation = new float[2];


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(mHeading, getWidth() * 0.5f, getHeight() * 0.5f);
        canvas.getMatrix().invert(invertedMatrix);
        mCanvas.delegate = canvas;
        super.dispatchDraw(mCanvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        centeringAllowed = false;

        float[] location = tempLocation;
        location[0] = ev.getX();
        location[1] = ev.getY();
        invertedMatrix.mapPoints(location);
        ev.setLocation(location[0], location[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```